# Cron Job for Django Project not activating

Tags: python, django, cron

I am trying to add a cronjob to my django project that will reset the scores of my game every 1 minutes.
I used cron tab and I think it’s my pathing/location of the function that is causing it to not trigger.
Here is the hierarchy of the files and a few files in each of them.

```
ProjectBackend—
    ProjectBackend—
        - settings.py
        - wsgi.py 
        __init__.py
        urls.py
    manage.py
    heroku
    scores—
        admin.py
        cron.py
        models.py
        views.py
        urls.py
        apps.py
```

In the settings.py above, I have the following : I added only crontab to installed_apps and the cronjob array.

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', ’scores.cron.my_scheduled_job’)
]
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'scores.apps.ScoresConfig',
    'django_crontab',
]
```

I have replaced  the cronjob’s second parameter with ’ProjectBackend.scores.cron.my_scheduled_job’  and other variations with no luck. I chose ‘scores’ instead of  'scores.apps.ScoresConfig'  because it is designed as the name in apps.py

I placed the function called my_scheduled_job in the cron.py in the above location.

Right now all the function does is print out a string, which does not show up on Terminal when I do the following in the directory where manage.py is located.

```
‘Python3 manage.py crontab add’ 
‘Python3 manage.py crontab show’
```

To which it says : Currently active jobs in crontab: ('*/1 * * * *', ‘scores.cron.my_scheduled_job')
After this, I do python3 manage.py runserver and nothing happens.

https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/ I followed this. Do I have everything set up correctly?

Comment: I would recommend to use a Django Command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/ and then creating a cronjob by editing the crontab list crontab -e and adding your own timing...

Comment: @eddwinpaz What would our equivalent be to placing it in the management/commands folder? Do we put management inside of scores?

Comment: please check this.. it might help you. https://coderwall.com/p/k5p6ag/run-django-commands-using-cron

Answer (score 0):

django_cronjob runs with crontab not with run server command

you can also use your manage command and write your code to that command and add it to crontab manually or when a function called with  python code.

Comment: How would one go about adding it manually?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like , there is something wrong with configuration of cronjob. You can visit this link given below:
http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_cron_configurations.html

You can also visit this link for more description about crontab
https://kite.com/python/docs/celery.task.schedules.crontab